# Macbook pro 15", late 2013: internet stopped working

Tags: wifi

I have a macbook pro 15", late 2013 with Catalina (10.15.4). It was working flawlessly until few hours ago, now internet won't work. I can't find any trace of hardware issue, the wifi card works fine and it connects to wifi networks. Unfortunately even with full signal internet doesn't work, even pinging from the terminal return the "unknown host" error. I don't have the ethernet adapter so I can't test it.

I tried different wifi networks, I tried forgetting the networking and connecting to it again, I have tried the wireless diagnostic, rebooting the laptop...no results so far...is there something else I can do?

EDIT: to add some context, I know that the wifi is working fine because two other computers and the phone have internet access via the same wifi network

EDIT: output of the command `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep "yiaddr\|router"`:

```
yiaddr = 192.168.1.63
router (ip_mult): {192.168.1.254}
```

EDIT: result of the various pings:

`ping 192.168.1.254`

```
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time 1.891ms
...
```

it seems to work, same thing for `ping 8.8.8.8`:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time 9.997ms
...
```

sadly, `ping www.google.com` still results in `ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host`

Comment: Connecting to a network and having Internet access are different things, but not mutually exclusive.  You can have network connectivity and no Internet, but you can’t have Internet without network.  So, how did you determine WiFi is working properly?  What’s your IP address and your default gateway?

Comment: Try issuing this command `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep "yiaddr\|router"` in Terminal.  Post the output to your question.  Change `en0` to your specific adapter.

Comment: Ok.  First, when you make an edit, @ me in **comments** so I get notified.  I just stumbled over this update by chance.  Next, try pinging the router - `ping 192.168.1.254`. If that works, try pinging Google’s DNS server - `ping 8.8.8.8`.  If that works, try `ping www.google.com`  Post results

Comment: @Allan I have updated the question!

Comment: It’s a DNS issue.  The fact that your machine *can* get out of your network and reach one of Google’s servers by IP, means the Internet works. Using the `ipconfig` command from above change the grep portion to look like this `grep “domain_name_server”`. Post the output

Comment: @Allan here's the output: "domain_name_server (ip_mult): {192.168.1.254}"

Comment: That means your router is acting as your DNS server.  Can you log into your router and check the config to make sure the DNS settings are correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Allan, you have been incredibly helpful. I changed the dns with the command `networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` and now internet is back!

Comment: If you want to post an answer, I'll upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Allan I found the answer. I had to change my dns with the following command:

`networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

after that internet was back!